# Similarity measures for Probability Mass Functions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, density-function, similarities

I am trying to predict whether two sets of papers are written by the same author by looking at the distribution of papers over the years (number of papers published in a given year).   
Suppose we have a first group X = { 1992:2, 1993:5, 1996:10, 1997:2, 1999:10} 
and a second group Y = {1992:1, 1994:3, 1996:2, 1997:5, 2000:3}.

The sets of papers in X and Y are disjoint. I think X and Y can be considered as PMFs. How can I calculate the similarity/distance between these two distributions? In other words, I am looking for some kind of non-parametric (I assume that the distribution of papers is not necessarily normal) statistical test to check whether X and Y are drawn from the same distribution of an author's publications.

Comment: I wonder whether this approach is really suited to solving the kind of problem you are describing.  How are these groups selected, exactly?  Are they collectively a complete account of all the author's papers or not? Are the years of publication known with complete accuracy or not?

Comment: Comparing the distribution of papers is only a small part of the overall methodology. I also take into account other factors, such as the similarity of the papers' domains, the overlap of co-authors, etc. The groups of papers belong to a certain ambiguous author name, e.g., papers in group X and Y belong to an ambiguous author name "W Chen"(could refer to Wei Chen or Weng Chen). The goal is to find out whether both groups belong to a single author or two different authors. And the publication years are  taken from the well-known digital libraries such as Microsoft Academic.

Comment: I cannot imagine what kind of distributions you might expect if these were the same author or two authors both working in the 1990s.

Comment: To explain it to you better, I have to explain the whole methodology in detail. I do not want to make the question more complicated to understand. Instead, can you please help me how to calculate the similarities between two PMFs based on the examples given (X and Y?